# Drupal Date api, dates are displayed as one day earlier than the date entered

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

i'm not sure what is going wrong, but I created a Date field, and though it has been working fine, on March 12, 2012 and beyond all dates entered are retrieved one day earlier. The fields in the node edit display the correct date, but retrieving is the problem. I'm not sure if it is a timezone issue? Why March 12, 2012 and past that?

I have a feeling it has something to do with UTC and DST, but i dont know what to do. In the Date and Time settings I have it set as america/toronto which is what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added the timezone when using the format_date function:

```
$date_start = format_date(strtotime($node->field_event_date[0][value]),$type='custom',$format='F j, Y',$timezone='America/Toronto');
```